# CreateFile Windows error in a Delphi THandleStream

Tags: delphi, winapi, stream, disk

I have a simple class derivated from THandleStream which I use to edit a raw volume. I call Windows createfile() function to open a drive but the function never returns a valid handle, rather an exotic error code( *348* at the debugtime and *304* at the runtime, but the error is not raised, this is just that the handle value looks wierd). this is what I'm doing:

```
Constructor TDiskStream.Create(Const aDrive: String);
Var
  Hdl: Cardinal;
  A,B: Int64;
Begin

  Hdl := CreateFile( PChar(ADrive), 
                     GENERIC_WRITE, 
                     FILE_SHARE_READ Or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                     0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

  Inherited Create( Hdl );
  GetDiskFreeSpaceEx( PChar( RightStr(ADrive,2) + '\'), A, FSize, @B );

End;
```

The handle value matchs to the error code described as **ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_GLOBAL_SHORT_NAME_REGISTRY_SETTING** on msdn, but it seems to be very uncommon. The *aDrive* parameter is set correctly ( in the format **\\.\x:** ).

What's wrong here, how can I manage to get my valid file handle ?

Answer (score 10):

`CreateFile` does not return error codes - it returns either a valid handle or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (-1). Here is a standard use of `CreateFile` function call with error check:

```
var
  H: THandle;

begin
  H:= CreateFile(PChar('\\.\D:'), GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  if H = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    raise Exception.Create(Format('Oops - error opening disk: %d', [GetLastError]));
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Those look like valid handle values to me. What makes you think they aren't?

CreateFile doesn't return error codes. If it fails, it returns Invalid_Handle_Value. The error code is given by calling GetLastError. For details on how those functions work, refer to the documentation on MSDN.

If CreateFile fails, I recommend you fail the constructor in turn by raising an exception:

```
if Hdl = Invalid_Handle_Value then
  RaiseLastOSError;
```